# Using the BucketManager in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a simple core library for my web app that I am using to test the Item Bucket API. I have a class of properties and methods where, for example, I would like to query through a movie item bucket in Sitecore using the properties and a constants class that stores the template IDs.

The problem I am having is when using the BucketManager class to call the static method **Search()**, it doesn't recognize the second param, **templates**:"String"

[image: BucketManager Sitecore GetAllMovies]

Has anyone had this problem before? I'm also having a BucketList problem in Sitecore where only the standard values of a template are showing a BucketList TemplateFilter source (request a screenshot if you're interested in this bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sitecore Item Bucket Developer Guide intended on excluding a non-optional parameter called **out hitCount**, which is an attribute that allows the paging of results. Without this parameter, I had an invalid method signature, which caused the error.

Here is the correct code:

```
public List<Item> GetAllMovies() {
            var hc = 0;
            return BucketManager.Search(
                MovieFolder, 
                out hc, 
                templates: Constants.Constants.TemplateIDs.MoviesItemTemplateID
            ).Select(i=> i.GetItem()).Where(i=>i != null).ToList();
        }
```

Also, don't forget to cast the IENumberable as a List of Items as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add such string

```
using Sitecore.ItemBucket.Kernel.ItemExtensions.Axes;
```

Comment: This class is used to replace GetChildren(), Children, and Axes methods. I am using the BucketManager class for the Search method, and coincidentally they both use the templates attribute. Check my answer below for the solution.